# Rails / Stripe - undefined method `stripe_token' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for payments on my Rails app and I've hit the error above. I've recently moved a big chunk of my code from my controller to model and this is the first time I've hit this error (I've tested payments before and it never came up). Not really sure why this is coming up now.

Here's my Model code -

**Booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    def reserve
    # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
    return unless valid?

    # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
    self.total_amount = quantity.to_i * event.price_pennies.to_i

    # Free events don't need to do anything special
    if event.is_free?
      save

    # Paid events should charge the customer's card
    else
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: total_amount, currency: "gbp", card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}", items: [{quantity: @booking.quantity}])
        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
        save
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        errors.add(:base, e.message)
        false
      end
     end 
  end
end
```

And in my controller -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

        if @booking.reserve
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end
    end
```

Here's the error message -

[image: Error message]

I'm pretty new to Rails so apologies if this seems straightforward, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message, so we know what line of code it's occurring on?  If it's in the model file, in the begin/rescue block, I don't see where you've defined the @booking object.

Comment: I've added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`@booking` is an instance variable that is only available in the context of the controller/view.  Since reserve is an instance method on the model, you probably just want to refer to `self` or nothing, i.e `@booking.method` => `self.method` or `method`.

Comment: So, I just put 'total_amount' or 'self.total_amount' ?